# record duplication in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, duplicates

Can anyone tell me how to delete duplicate records or avoid duplication in the first place?

The problem is that whenever I edit a record, a duplicate record is created.

Can anyone please send an answer??

Comment: You need to provide more information. What "records" are you talking about? There is no such thing as a "record" in pure C++, so please provide more information.

Comment: we're going to need more information to answer this.

how are your records stored?  how are you editing them?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use std::map or std::set collections. They don't store duplicates.
Some containers have methods like unique() or you can just use unique() or unique_if() algorithms.
By the way where do you duplicate records? Is it a problem with ado(.net) usage or maybe with some specific collection you use?
Where do you see duplicated records? In memory, in db or maybe in some file?

Alek

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to avoiding duplicates, regardless of language, is to use a hashtable to store your records.  This assumes there is a field which serves as a unique identifier.  Doctor Dobb's Journal as an article on [C++ and hashing](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/198800559).